# R convert irregular character to date

Tags: r

I am a R newbie!  I am trying to convert irregular characters to dates and at the same time drop the time, but keep getting NA, For example:

```
test = as.POSIXct(strptime("6/2/2013 10:27","10/21/2013 3:04"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Funny! Were the 3:04 et al. in your question earlier? I seem to have missed those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what strptime is supposed to do, but if you just replace it with c() then your function works fine.  It would also work with `as.Date`

```
test = as.POSIXct(c("6/2/2013 10:27","10/21/2013 3:04"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
test = as.Date(c("6/2/2013 10:27","10/21/2013 3:04"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Ahh, now I know what that c does.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
R> as.Date(c("6/2/2013", "10/21/2013"), format="%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2013-06-02" "2013-10-21"
```

or

```
R> as.POSIXct(c("6/2/2013", "10/21/2013"), format="%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2013-06-02 IST" "2013-10-21 IST"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start dealing with dates in R, I urge you to try the `lubridate` package, it simplify a lot this kind of operation.

```
require(lubridate)
date_string <- c("6/2/2013", "10/21/2013")
mdy(date_string)
[1] "2013-06-02 UTC" "2013-10-21 UTC"
```

For example here,  in the function `mdy`, `m` stand for month, `d` for day and `y` for year and all the others functions are that intuitive.

Check the vignette to have a better idea of its possibilities

```
vignette("lubridate", package = "lubridate")
```

Comment: Good thing for suggesting `lubridate`.

Comment: @asb Thks. I remember when I started with dates manipulation at that I wish I could have something like lubridate.

Answer (score 0):

Try as.Date("6/2/2013", format="%m/%d/%Y"). But mind that you will get the same result even if your "irregular" character is "6/2/2013abcd"

Comment: @slammaster has a complete answer, I missed the time part.